# Pattern not matching

Tags: regex

I’m trying to figure out how to make;

`/section/hello-news/goodbye-news`

Match when this pattern is used (a single group)

`/section/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)`

But with the way I have it setup only `/section/hello-news` matches. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have 3 parts, so use `/section/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)`

Comment: you didn't have slash in `[]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't that create two groups? I'm matching this to a path that can be either one or the other

Comment: Then `/section/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)` - even easier. You did not specify what *is* wrong with the example you posted, so, we can only guess what you need.

Comment: I specified that it needed to be a single group and what worked and what didn't. Not sure what else you want me to include? That did solve the issue though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the forward slash `/`, try this:

```
/section/([A-Za-z0-9\/-]+)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW9aN9/1)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct regex, just add another group:

`\/section\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/mP0wN2/1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the trailing `/` on `hello-news`, and allowing it to repeat.

```
/section(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+
```

This way, it matches any number of subdirectories. i.e. '/section/foo/bar/baz'.

If you are using the matches, you can also ignore the slash by making it non-capturing:

```
/section/(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))+
```